# CNContactstore - Label of a phone number returning null in iOS 9.3.4 and 9.3.5

Tags: ios, cncontact, cncontactstore

I have a weird problem and I hope this is Apple's bug. let me know if this is a Apple bug.

Steps

- Open Dialer
- Dial a number and add to contacts using + sign as number1
- Open contacts and add number2 to contacts using contacts app

Now the below code returns

```
    for (CNLabeledValue *labelObj in contact.phoneNumbers) {
    phone = [labelObj.value stringValue];
    CNLabeledValue *cnPhoneLabel = [CNLabeledValue labeledValueWithLabel:labelObj.label value:labelObj.value];
    NSString *phoneLabelString = [[CNLabeledValue localizedStringForLabel:cnPhoneLabel.label] capitalizedString];
    }
```

**number1**

```
    "<CNLabeledValue: 0x148306800: 
identifier=08C1A708-F5A2-4A65-AB08-024B3FCF79C4, label=(null), 
value=<CNPhoneNumber: 0x148297aa0: countryCode=in, digits=2586352952356>>"
```

**number2**

```
"<CNLabeledValue: 0x148296a60:
identifier=7D9ABC9E-D5AF-421D-BFF6-7902BC99E80F, label=_$!<Mobile>!$_,
value=<CNPhoneNumber: 0x148296aa0: countryCode=in, digits=7392>>"
```

number1 label returns label as null

> NLabeledValue: 0x148306800:
>   identifier=08C1A708-F5A2-4A65-AB08-024B3FCF79C4, label=(null)

Comment: Issue still exist with iOS 12. the label displayed in Contact app is "phone" , but when we try to fetch using CNLabeledValue, then its empty